# Select a directory with ftp_get

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I'm developing a plugin in WordPress to download a file periodically using ftp_get.
This is the line:

```
(ftp_get( $conn_id, "file.zip", $file, FTP_BINARY )
```

When I write the name of file, the download is correct, but I don't know what location is saved. If I write:

```
(ftp_get( $conn_id, "/ftp_files/file.zip", $file, FTP_BINARY )
```

An error occurs. 
How I can select the desired directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from manual:

`bool ftp_get ( resource $ftp_stream , string $local_file , string $remote_file , int $mode [, int $resumepos = 0 ] )`

its a normal relative address, so if you run your script in folder

`myscript/myfolder/`

and you type `"file.zip"` as `$local_file`, it will be saved to `myscript/myfolder`...

id advise to always check if that folder exists and is writable by using `is_writable($filename)`

edit: if you include your script in a different file (for example you have an index.php, that includes your script), then the folder you will be in by default will be the folder of the index.php file, not the script).

If you want to be sure where you are, just use

`dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` before the `$local_file` path, both these constructs will give you the address to the folder of the file the script is located in

Comment: Running in plugin of WordPress, the file is not in the plugin's folder.

Comment: @josearcos then as I said, use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__`, like 

`ftp_get( $conn_id, dirname(__FILE__)."/file.zip", $file, FTP_BINARY )`

Comment: I see where the file is saved, but, how i can select the desired folder? i.e. if I want to save the file in a folder that's in the path /ftp_files/?

Comment: I dont understand. You can normally navigate through the folders with `dirname(__FILE__)."/file.zip"`, like `dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../myfolder/file.zip"`

Comment: Yes I know, but downloading the file with ftp_get or ftp_fget, I write a var $localfile = "orders.csv". How I save this file in other folder, and not in the default folder?

Comment: then write 

`$localfile = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../myfolder/file.zip"`

Im sorry but you appparently miss basic understanding of folder system...

Comment: Yes, that's work! Thanks you very much, I know the folder system navigation, but I don't know how to use in PHP, thanks.